# ¿Cómo funciona la medalla electorado?

Tags: soporte, medallas

En la sugerencia de proximas medallas me sale como sugerida la medalla electorado que dice:

> Votar en 600 preguntas y que el 25 % o más del total de votos esté en
>   las preguntas

Mi duda viene dada por que tengo 836 votos emitidos entre preguntas y respuestas, de los cuales 582 son por preguntas y 254 por respuesta. Sin embargo ya tendría el 25 por ciento en votos de preguntas, lo que cumple la  condición de la medalla, pero veo que el contador de votos en preguntas pone 582/600.

¿Simplemente la medalla se otorga al votar en las 600 preguntas?, o ¿Que hace ese 25% de votos en las preguntas?

A mi parecer esta de más esa descripción del 25%.

Comment: Un matiz importante: en 600 preguntas **distintas**

Comment: @MiquelColl eso deberia de agregarse en la descripcion de la medalla

Comment: Yo creo que al decir "Votar en 600 preguntas" ya queda claro que son preguntas distintas, una pregunta contiene una pregunta y puede tener varias respuestas pero nunca más preguntas, no dice emitir 600 votos. Para mi está claro.

Comment: Posible duplicado de [Lista de todas las medallas con su descripción completa](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2699/lista-de-todas-las-medallas-con-su-descripci%c3%b3n-completa)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

La descripción da lugar a una mala interpretación (yo lo había interpretado mal de la descripción en inglés).

Para obtenerla, hay que

1. votar en **600 preguntas** (preguntas, no incluye respuestas).
2. tener el **25%** de los votos emitidos (para todas las publicaciones) **en preguntas**.

---

Esto es más fácil de observar desde tu perfil, configurando cuál es la siguiente medalla que querés seguir. En tu caso, votaste 581 preguntas (faltan 19 para llegar a 600), con un porcentaje de 69% de preguntas/total (superaste ampliamente el 25%).

[image: Siguiendo la medalla electorado de Juan Pinzon se observa que no llega a 600 preguntas]

Comment: El 25% no se cumpliría si, por ejemplo, votaste 600 preguntas y 1900 respuestas. Entonces, `600 / (600 + 1900) = 600 / 2500 = 0.24 = 24%` ... En ese caso, tendrías 600 preguntas pero deberías votar más preguntas para llegar al 25%.

Answer (score -2):

Lo que dice @Mariano es incorrecto... La división no se hace entre las preguntas y las respuestas votadas.

La cosa es de la siguiente manera. Supongamos una pregunta cualquiera, tiene `10` votos a favor, y tiene varias respuestas, y en cada una de esas respuestas, los votos son por ejemplo, `[4, 3, 1, 0, 0, -2]`... Luego se hace la sumatoria de la pregunta junto con las respuestas. `10 + (4+3+1+0+0-2) -> 10 + 6 -> 16 ... 100* (10/16)` tiene que ser mayor o igual a `25`, y ese es el `%25`.

Comment: Errrr..... Creo que no.

Comment: @MiquelColl Acabo de votar algunas preguntas, y al final era cierto, me equivoqué yo.