# Lista de todas las medallas con su descripción completa

Tags: soporte, faq, medallas

> Esta publicación está basada en la pregunta [List of all badges with full descriptions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/67397/209901)

- ¿Cuál es el requisito para conseguir la medalla X?
- ¿Por qué no he recibido *aún* la medalla X?
- ¿Qué medallas puedo ganar múltiples veces?

> **Salta a:**
>
> - [Medallas por preguntas](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2700/83)
> - [Medallas por respuestas](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2705/83)
> - [Medallas de participación](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2709/83)
> - [Medallas por etiquetas](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2708/83)
> - [Medallas de moderación](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2711/83)
> - [Otras medallas](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2706/83)
> - [¿Por qué no recibí aún la medalla X?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2701/83)

Nota: Algunas medallas se entregan en base a la **puntuación**. El término puntuación se refiere al resultado de restar el número de votos negativos al número de votos positivos.

> Visita la sección [Medallas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges) o el [Centro de Ayuda](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help) para ver la lista completa de medallas. Podrás filtrarlas por tipo, ganadas o no ganadas.

[Regresar al índice del FAQ](/q/7931)

Answer (score 10):

## Medallas de preguntas

[Vuelve a la pregunta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2699/83)

---

#### Altruista

- bronce; entregada una vez
- Primera recompensa que otorgas manualmente en la pregunta de otra persona

  - *Otorgas manualmente* quiere decir seleccionar un ganador de la recompensa; si es el sistema otorga la mitad, no cuenta ([fuente](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/67957/209901)).
- No se entrega en los Meta propios, pues no disponen de recompensas.

---

#### Benefactor

- bronce; entregada una vez
- Primera recompensa que otorgas manualmente en tu propia pregunta

  - *Otorgas manualmente* quiere decir seleccionar un ganador de la recompensa; si es el sistema otorga la mitad, no cuenta ([fuente](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/67957/209901)), ni tampoco dejar que el sistema la entregue íntegramente a una respuesta aceptada.
- No se entrega en los Meta propios, pues no disponen de recompensas.

---

#### Curioso

- bronce; entregada una vez
- Formula una pregunta que sea bien recibida en 5 días diferentes y mantén un registro de preguntas positivas

#### Inquisitivo

- plata; entregada una vez
- Formula una pregunta que sea bien recibida en 30 días diferentes y mantén un registro de preguntas positivas

#### Socrático

- oro; entregada múltiples veces
- Formula una pregunta que sea bien recibida en 100 días diferentes y mantén un registro de preguntas positivas

**Criterios adicionales para esta familia de medallas:**

- Cualquier pregunta abierta que no está eliminada y tiene puntuación >= 1 se considera *bien recibida*. Si es cerrada o eliminada pasados 60 días desde que se formuló, sigue considerándose bien recibida.
- Solamente los días donde *todas* las preguntas son bien recibidas cuentan ([fuente](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/262301))
- Un registro positivo de preguntas quiere decir que, en general, no tienes demasiadas preguntas cerradas, votadas negativamente o eliminadas. La fórmula es `(total preguntas - preguntas con puntaje negativo - cerradas - borradas)/total preguntas ≥ 0.5`. ¡Las preguntas que han sido votadas negativamente *y* cerradas *y* eliminadas cuentan tres veces en este cálculo!

---

#### Pregunta favorita

- plata; entregada múltiples veces
- Tener una pregunta marcada como favorita por 25 usuarios.

#### Pregunta estelar

- oro; entregada múltiples veces
- Tener una pregunta marcada como favorita por 100 usuarios.

---

#### Inversor

- bronce; entregada una vez
- Primera recompensa que ofreces en la pregunta de otra persona
- No se entrega en los Meta propios, pues no disponen de recompensas.

---

#### Pregunta interesante

- bronce; entregada múltiples veces
- Pregunta con puntuación de 10 o más

#### Buena pregunta

- plata; entregada múltiples veces
- Pregunta con puntuación de 25 o más

#### Excelente pregunta

- oro; entregada múltiples veces
- Pregunta con puntuación de 100 o más

---

#### Pregunta popular

- bronce; entregada múltiples veces
- Recibir 1000 vistas a una pregunta

#### Pregunta destacada

- plata; entregada múltiples veces
- Recibir 2500 vistas a una pregunta

#### Pregunta famosa

- oro; entregada múltiples veces
- Recibir 10 000 vistas a una pregunta

---

#### Promotor

- bronce; entregada una vez
- Ofrecer una recompensa a tu propia pregunta
- No se entrega en los Meta propios, pues no disponen de recompensas.

---

#### Erudito

- bronce; entregada una vez
- Aceptar una respuesta

---

#### Estudiante

- bronce; entregada una vez
- Alcanzar una puntuación de 1 en una pregunta

---

#### Estepicursor (retirada)

- bronce; entregada una vez
- Formular una pregunta que durante su primera semana de existencia tiene una puntuación de 0, ninguna respuesta, ningún comentario y [no más de 60 visitas](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252304/tumbleweed-badge-how-low-exactly-is-low-views?noredirect=1#comment7357_252304).
- Esta medalla fue [retirada en junio de 2019](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/06/18/adios-to-unfriendly-badges-ahoy-lifejacket-and-lifeboat/).

Answer (score 6):

## Otras medallas

[Vuelve a la pregunta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2699/lista-de-todas-las-medallas-con-su-descripci%C3%B3n-completa#question)

---

### Analítico

- bronce; entregada una vez **retirada**
- Visitar cada sección de las preguntas frecuentes (retirado)
- A partir de junio de 2013, esta medalla ya no se entrega debido a que la [FAQ (sección de las preguntas frecuentes) se ha cambiado al Centro de Ayuda en toda la red](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/183128/analytical-badge-still-showing-faq/183243#183243). A quienes se les entregó esta medalla aún la tienen.

---

### Anunciante

- bronce; entregada múltiples veces
- Compartir un vínculo a una publicación posteriormente visitada desde 25 direcciones IP únicas

### Refuerzo

- plata; entregada múltiples veces
- Compartir un vínculo a una publicación posteriormente visitada desde 300 direcciones IP únicas

### Publicista

- oro; entregada múltiples veces
- Compartir un vínculo a una publicación posteriormente visitada desde 1000 direcciones IP únicas

**Criterios adicionales para esta familia de medallas:**

- La fecha en que se hizo la pregunta es irrelevante
- Sólo cuentan los clics desde *fuera* de la red de Stack Exchange hacia la pregunta vinculada
- Introducido en publicación en el blog de Stack Overflow *[Medallas Anunciante, Refuerzo, y Publicista](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/09/09/announcer-booster-and-publicist-badges/)* (aunque [se cambió el requisito de direcciones IP únicas](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/68082) y [se eliminó el requisito de límite de tiempo](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/118509)).

---

### Informado

- bronce; entregada una vez
- Leer la página del [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) completa
- Introducido como parte de la nueva guía de "Inicio rápido"
- No se otorga en las Metas por sitio, ya que esta página en Meta redirige a la página en el sitio principal.
- La primera medalla que se entrega inmediatamente y no por un trabajo programado.

---

### No soy un robot

- plata; entregada múltiples veces
- Conoció a un empleado de Stack Overflow en un [evento donde un empleado de Stack Overflow fue un organizador o participante](https://es.stackoverflow.com/badges/get/events) con más de 50 asistentes
- [Introducido para promover la socialización](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/335432/a-new-silver-badge-that-robots-simply-cant-win) en Stack Overflow y posteriormente en Stack Overfow en español: [Una nueva medalla de plata que los robots no pueden ganar](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1693/83)
- La primera medalla que se otorga manualmente
- Especificada solamente por Stack Overflow

Answer (score 5):

## Medallas por respuestas

[Vuelve a la pregunta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2699/lista-de-todas-las-medallas-con-su-descripci%C3%B3n-completa#question)

---

### Iluminado

- plata; entregada múltiples veces
- Primero en responder, y respuesta aceptada con una puntuación de 10 o más

---

### Explicador

- bronce; entregada una vez
- Editar y responder 1 pregunta (ambas acciones dentro de 12 horas, puntuación de la respuesta > 0)

### Refinador

- plata; entregada una vez
- Editar y contestar 50 preguntas (ambas acciones dentro de 12 horas, puntuación de la respuesta > 0)

### Iluminador

- oro; entregada una vez
- Editar y responder 500 preguntas (ambas acciones en un plazo de 12 horas, puntuación de la respuesta > 0)

**Criterios adicionales para esta familia de medallas:**

- Las respuestas deben tener una puntuación de 1 o mayor.
- Las auto-respuestas no cuentan.
- Sólo cuentan las ediciones de cuerpo y título en las preguntas, las ediciones de sólo etiqueta no.
- La pregunta debe permanecer abierta.

---

### Generalista

- plata; entregada una vez
- Proporcionar respuestas que no son wiki de comunidad con una puntuación total de 15 en 20 de las 40 etiquetas principales
- Solo entregada una vez cada una de las 40 etiquetas más utilizadas supera las 200 preguntas ([confirmación](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/22176338#22176338))

---

### Gurú

- plata; entregada múltiples veces
- Respuesta aceptada y puntuación de 40 o más
- Las respuestas wiki de comunidad sí pueden dar pie a ganar esta medalla

---

### Chaleco salvavidas

- plata; entregable múltiples veces
- Responder una pregunta que tiene una puntuación de -2 o menos.
- La pregunta después debe llegar a una puntuación de 2 o más en algún momento después de que tú hayas publicado tu respuesta.
- Tu respuesta debe tener una puntuación de 5 o más.

### Bote salvavidas

- oro; entregable múltiples veces
- Responder una pregunta que tiene una puntuación de -3 o menos.
- La pregunta después debe llegar a una puntuación de 3 o más en algún momento después de que tú hayas publicado tu respuesta.
- Tu respuesta debe tener una puntuación de 20 o más.

---

### Respuesta interesante

- bronce; entregada múltiples veces
- Puntuación de respuestas de 10 o más

### Buena respuesta

- plata; entregada múltiples veces
- Respuesta con puntuación de 25 o más

### Excelente respuesta

- oro; entregada múltiples veces
- Puntuación de respuestas de 100 o más

---

### Populista

- oro; entregada múltiples veces
- Respuesta con la puntuación más alta, que superó por más del doble la puntuación superior a 10 de una respuesta aceptada
- Debe cumplir todos estos requisitos ([fuente](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/6886)):

  - ser la respuesta con mayor puntuación en esa pregunta ([fuente](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/6938))
  - no estar aceptada
  - tener puntuación de 23 o más
  - tener una puntuación al menos un punto mayor que el doble de la puntuación de la respuesta aceptada
  - la respuesta aceptada debe tener puntuación de 11 o más
  - no ser una respuesta a tu propia pregunta
    it is not an answer to your own question ([fuente](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/119221))

---

### Reversión (retirada)

- oro; entregada múltiples veces
- Proporcionar una respuesta con una puntuación de +20 a una pregunta con una puntuación de -5
- Esta medalla fue [retirada en junio de 2019](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/06/18/adios-to-unfriendly-badges-ahoy-lifejacket-and-lifeboat/).

---

### Resurgimiento

- bronce; entregada múltiples veces
- Primera respuesta a una pregunta tras más de 30 días desde su formulación, con una puntuación de 2 o más
- Tu respuesta llega a una puntuación de dos.
- No hay otras respuestas publicadas anteriormente a la tuya que tengan una puntuación de 2.
- *Anteriormente* se refiere al momento en el que la respuesta fue publicada (su primera revisión).

### Nigromante

- plata; entregada múltiples veces
- Responder una pregunta después de más de 60 días con una puntuación de 5 o más

---

### Autodidacta

- bronce; entregada una vez
- Responder tu propia pregunta con puntuación de 3 o más
- Es válida en respuestas wiki de comunidad

---

### Profesor

- bronce; entregada una vez
- Responder una pregunta con puntuación de 1 o más

---

### Tenaz

- plata; entregada una vez
- Respuestas aceptadas con puntuación de cero: más de 5, 20% del total
- Fue [originalmente llamada Incansable](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/improvements-to-badge-system/).

### Héroe anónimo

- oro; entregada una vez
- Respuestas aceptadas con puntuación de cero: más de 10, 25% del total

**Criterios adicionales para esta familia de medallas:**

- Sólo se consideran las respuestas aceptadas con al menos diez días de antigüedad ([fuente](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/57834))
- Las respuestas de la wiki de comunidad, las respuestas eliminadas y las respuestas aceptadas no se incluyen en los cálculos

Comment: Tremendo trabajo, ¡muchas gracias Cesar!

Comment: ¿Estás traduciendo otras respuestas? Para no hacerlo yo si estás ahora mismo con otra.

Comment: Todo sea por nutrir la Comunidad. Y pues tremendo el trabajo tuyo también. No mi amigo, no estoy traduciendo ninguna otra.

Comment: He editado la respuesta para añadir todo aquello que quedó sin copiar de la [respuesta original](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/68258/209901).

Answer (score 5):

## Medallas de participación

[Vuelve a la pregunta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2699/83)

---

#### Autobiógrafo

- bronce; entregada una vez
- Añadir algo en el campo “Acerda de mí” del perfil de usuario ([fuente](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/239938))

---

#### Asamblea

- bronce; entregada múltiples veces
- Visita la [página de elecciones](https://es.stackoverflow.com/election) cuando una elección está activa
- Se debe tener el mínimo de reputación requerida para poder votar en la elección
- Se entrega una vez por elección, siempre y cuando se visite la página de elecciones durante una fase de la elección (nominación, primarias o elección) está en proceso

#### Votante

- plata; entregada múltiples veces
- Votar a al menos un candidato en la fase elección de unas elecciones a moderador de la comunidad.

**Criterios adicionales para esta familia de medallas:**

- Introducida [durante las elecciones de 2012 para moderador de Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.blog/2012/06/08/election-participation-badges/)
- No está disponible en los Meta propios, pues no tienen elecciones

---

#### Comentarista

- bronce; entregada una vez
- Publicar un total de diez comentarios

#### Entendido

- plata; entregada una vez
- Dejar diez comentarios que tengan una puntuación de al menos 5
- Los comentarios en publicaciones eliminadas sí cuentan para esta medalla ([fuente](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/109629/255554)), los comentarios eliminados no ([fuente](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/79555/255554))
- Nunca habrá una medalla de oro para este tipo ([fuente](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/78049))

---

#### Entusiasta

- plata; entregada una vez
- Visitar el sitio 30 días consecutivos

#### Fanatic

- oro; entregada una vez
- Visitar el sitio 100 días consecutivos

**Criterios adicionales para esta familia de medallas:**

- Cargar el sitio solamente **no** es suficiente para que compute como "visita" ([fuente](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66485))

  - La cantidad exacta de actividad requerida para que compute como visita no se ha revelado
- Cada "día" va de la medianoche UTC al momento antes de la medianoche, UTC; los días **no** se cuentan en tiempo local

---

#### Birrete

- bronce; entregada una vez
- Ganar una reputación de al menos 200 en un solo día

#### Épico

- plata; entregada una vez
- Ganar una reputación de al menos 200 en 50 días

#### Legendario

- oro; entregada una vez
- Ganar una reputación de al menos 200 en 150 días

**Criterios adicionales para esta familia de medallas:**

- Todas las actividades que dan reputación positiva cuentan, excepto los bonus de asociación: votos positivos, respuestas aceptadas, recompensas y sugerencias de edición ([fuente](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/88526))
- Los votos negativos recibidos o dados no cuentan para esta medalla. ([fuente](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/181103))
- Cada "día" va de la medianoche UTC al momento antes de la medianoche, UTC; los días **no** se cuentan en tiempo local
- Esta medalla también se entrega en Meta ([fuente](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/79968/209901))

---

#### Precognitivo

- bronce; entregada una vez
- Entregada a aquellos que le dieron a "follow" en la propuesta en [Area 51](https://area51.stackexchange.com/) antes de que entrara en la [fase "commitment"](https://area51.stackexchange.com/faq), cuando el sitio entra en la fase beta privada.

  - En otras palabras, sirve para marcar a la gente que ha estado por aquí y dado soporte al sitio antes incluso de que se lanzara.
  - No se puede ganar en todos los sitios; en particular, aquellos que se lanzaron antes de que se creara el proceso de creación de sitios a través de Area 51, como Stack Overflow, Super User y Server Fault
  - A pesar de esto, aparece en la lista de medallas para todos los sitios [para informar e incentivar la participación en Area 51](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/71737).

#### Beta

- plata; entregada una vez
- Participar activamente en la fase beta privada de un sitio haciendo lo siguiente:

  - Votar 10 veces
  - Añadir 3 publicación con puntuación > 0
  - Visitar el sitio 3 días distintos
- Los tres requisitos deben cumplirse antes de que el sitio entre en beta público (o al menos antes de que el script de la medalla corra)
- No se entrega en los sitios Meta, incluido Meta Stack Exchange

---

#### Quórum

- bronce; entregada una vez
- Tener una publicación con puntuación de 2 o más en el sitio Meta asociado

#### Convención

- plata; entregada una vez
- Tener al menos diez publicaciones con puntuación de 2 o más en el sitio Meta asociado

**Criterios adicionales para esta familia de medallas:**

- Por definición, no disponible en los sitios Meta, incluido Meta Stack Exchange

---

#### Conversador

- bronce; entregada una vez
- Publicar al menos diez mensajes en el chat
- Recibir al menos una estrella a un comentario en el chat
- También cuentan los mensajes de chat en salas privadas

#### Franco

- plata; entregada una vez
- Recibir estrellas de al menos diez usuarios diferentes en al menos 10 mensajes de chat diferentes
- Cada mensaje se cuenta una sola vez y cada usuario se cuenta una sola vez. Por ello, no es suficiente con que un mensaje reciba estrella de nueva personas y un décimo usuario dé estrella a nueve otros mensajes.
- Esta es una definición precisa: *Consider the bipartite graph whose vertices are all your messages and all the users, and whose edges are the stars you received. So a user (vertex) and a message (vertex) are connected by an edge if and only if the given user has starred the given message. You are eligible for the Outspoken badge if and only if this graph has a [matching number](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Matching.html) of at least ten.*

---

#### Añejo

- plata; entregada múltiples veces
- Tener una reputación de al menos `(número de años desde que se registró) × 200 + 1 (reputación inicial)`

  - El número de años no se restringe a íntegros e incremente contínuamente. Por ejemplo, si a los 2 años no tiene la reputación requerida de 400, el número de años sigue creciendo. Así, a mitad de camino de los 3 años (es decir, a los 2,5 años), necesitarás `2.5 × 200 = 500` de reputación para optar a la segunda medalla Añejo.
  - Si en cualquier momento cumples los requisitos para la medalla de este año, recibirás todas las medallas que habías dejado de ganar previamente hasta este año, sin importar cuándo corra el script otra vez.
  - La medalla solía requerir solamente  `(años) × 100 reputación`, pero se cambió [tras la implementación del bonus de asociación](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/32626)

Answer (score 4):

#### ¿Por qué no recibí *aún* la medalla X?

(A pesar de que el indicador de mi progreso en una medalla de mi perfil  indica que ya he ganado una medalla, e incluso recibí el mensaje "Felicidades - ganaste la medalla X")

---

La mayoría de medallas (con excepción de la [medalla Informado](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/164073)) se entregan a través de un trabajo programado que corre cada hora y son [no determinísticas](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/125108/295232), es decir, no existe *garantía* de que tu medalla se vaya a entregar dentro de la próxima hora.

Las medallas por etiquetas se basan en la reputación de etiqueta, que se calcula cada día (muy por la mañana, UTC), por lo que las medallas por etiqueta se entregan aún con menos frecuencia.

Más información en:
[How long does it take for badges to be awarded? How are they generated?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/1716/295232)

Answer (score 3):

## Medallas de moderación

[Volver a la pregunta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2699/83)

---

#### Patrulla ciudadana

- bronce; entregada una vez
- Reportar una publicación

#### Ayudante

- plata; entregada una vez
- Levantar 80 reportes considerados *útiles* por los moderadores o el sistema

#### Mariscal

- oro; entregada una vez
- Levantar 500 reportes considerados *útiles* por los moderadores o el sistema

**Criterios adicionales para esta familia de medallas:**

- No se entrega a moderadores diamantados, solo a usuarios registrados regulares ([fuente](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/146173/135907)).

---

#### Obligación civil

- plata; entregada una vez
- Realizar 300 votos

  - Cuentan los votos positivos y negativos a preguntas y respuestas
  - Los votos a comentarios **no** cuentan
  - Los votos en publicaciones wiki de comunidad **sí** cuentan

---

#### Limpieza

- bronce; entregada una vez
- Realizar una [reversión](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/816/83) a alguna publicación.

---

#### Agente

- oro; entregada una vez
- Servir como moderador *pro-tempore* durante un año o durante la graduación del sitio

#### Alguacil

- oro; entregada una vez
- Servir como moderador electo contínuamente durante un año

---

#### Crítico

- bronce; entregada una vez
- Realizar un voto negativo

  - Requiere de una reputación de 125 ([tabla de comparación de requisitos](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/58587))

---

#### Custodio

- bronce; entregada una vez por cola de revisión
- Realizar una labor de revisión.
- La revisión no tiene porqué realizarse a través de /review. Esto quiere decir que los usuarios con reputación baja pueden ganar la medalla al revisar una sugerencia de edición en una de sus propias publicaciones.

#### Revisor

- plata; entregada una vez por cola de revisión
- Revisar 250 publicaciones de una cola de revisión

#### Encargado

- oro; entregada una vez por cola de revisión
- Revisar 1000 publicaciones de una cola de revisión

---

#### Disciplinado

- bronce; entregada una vez
- Eliminar una de tus publicaciones que tiene una puntuación de 3 o más en el momento de eliminarse.
- No cuentan las publicaciones que son tuyas pero que no has eliminado tú.

---

#### Editor

- bronce; entregada una vez
- Editar el título o el cuerpo de cualquier publicación (incluyendo las tuyas)

#### Cervantes

- plata; entregada una vez
- Realizar un total de 80 ediciones entre preguntas, respuestas y wikis de etiqueta.

#### Editor de textos

- oro; entregada una vez
- Realizar un total de 500 ediciones entre preguntas, respuestas y wikis de etiqueta.

**Criterios adicionales para esta familia de medallas:**

- No cuentan las ediciones a publicaciones borradas.
- No cuentan las ediciones a tus propias publicaciones ([fuente](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/442))
- Sí que cuentan las ediciones a publicaciones wiki de comunidad ([fuente](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/442))
- No cuentan las ediciones que solamente consisten en cambios de etiqueta ([fuente](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/442))
- Sí que cuentan las ediciones de wikis de etiqueta ([fuente](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/442))
- Sí que cuentan las ediciones que sugieres antes de ganar el [privilegio de editar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit), una vez se han aprobado ([fuente](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/76916))
- Cada publicación editada cuenta una única vez, independientemente del número de ediciones que se hagan ulteriormente.

---

#### Electorado

- oro; entregada una vez
- Votar en 600 preguntas
- Que al menos un 25% del *número total de votos* realizados (en preguntas y respuestas) sea a preguntas
- Los votos a comentarios no cuentan

Dado que esta medalla parece confundir bastante, a continuación se detallan algunos ejemplos. `Total` es el número de votos realizados (`Preguntas` + `Respuestas`) y `Ratio` es la proporción de votos realizados a preguntas.

```
┌───────────┬────────────┬───────┬───────┬──────────────────────────┐  
│ Preguntas │ Respuestas │ Total │ Ratio │   ¿Electorado entregada? │  
├───────────┼────────────┼───────┼───────┼──────────────────────────┤  
│       600 │       2400 │  3000 │   20% │ No; ratio demasiado baja │  
│       201 │        401 │   602 │  ~33% │      No; < 600 preguntas │  
│       599 │          0 │   599 │  100% │      No; < 600 preguntas │  
│       600 │          0 │   600 │  100% │                       Sí │  
│       500 │        500 │  1000 │   50% │      No; < 600 preguntas │  
│       650 │        650 │  1300 │   50% │                       Sí │  
└───────────┴────────────┴───────┴───────┴──────────────────────────┘
```

---

#### Excavador

- bronce; entregada una vez
- Editar la primera publicación que estuvo inactiva durante 6 meses

#### Arqueólogo

- plata; entregada una vez
- Editar 100 publicaciones que estuvieron inactivas durante 6 meses

**Criterios adicionales para esta familia de medallas:**

- Las ediciones a tus propias publicaciones no cuentan ([fuente](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/115018))
- Los criterios específicos sobre qué ediciones cuentan para estas medallas es [vago y desconocido](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/184012)

---

#### Organizador

- bronce; entregada una vez
- Primer reetiquetado de una pregunta realizada por otro usuario (no tu propia pregunta)

---

#### Presión de pares

- bronce; entregada una vez
- Eliminar una de tus publicaciones que tiene una puntuación de -3 o menos en el momento de eliminarse.
- No cuentan las publicaciones que son tuyas pero que no has eliminado tú.

---

#### Corrector

- bronce; entregada una vez
- Aprobar o rechazar 100 sugerencias de edición.

---

#### Espíritu deportivo

- plata; entregada una vez
- Realizar 100 votos positivos en respuestas que compiten con una tuya ([fuente](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/68156))

  - Si contestas a una pregunta y consigues una puntuación de al menos 1, el resto de respuestas a esa pregunta se consideran "respuestas que compiten con la tuya"
  - No cuentan las publicaciones eliminadas
  - Los votos retraídos no cuentan
- Propuesta inicialmente [en junio de 2009](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/1215); [implementada en octubre de 2010](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/vote-early-vote-often/).

---

#### Sufragio

- bronce; entregada una vez
- Realizar 30 votos en preguntas o respuestas en un solo día.

  - Cada "día" va de la medianoche UTC al momento antes de la medianoche, UTC; los días no se cuentan en tiempo local
- [Propuesta inicialmente en junio de 2009](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/1264); implementeda en octubre de 2010.

---

#### Apoyador

- bronce; entregada una vez
- Realizar un voto

  - Suele requerir una reputación de 15 ([tabla de comparación de reputaciones](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/58587))

---

#### Creador de sinónimos

- bronce; entregada una vez
- Conseguir que se apruebe una sugerencia de sinónimo de etiqueta que hayas propuesta.

---

#### Editor de etiquetas

- bronce; entregada una vez
- Editar una entrada de wiki de etiqueta

#### Asistente de investigación

- plata; entregada una vez
- Editar 50 cuerpos de wikis de etiqueta diferentes
- Puedes editar una wiki de etiqueta o crear una nueva.
- No cuentan las ediciones a los extractos de la wiki de etiqueta ([fuente](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/121484))

---

#### Taxónomo

- plata; entregada una vez
- Crear una etiqueta que se usa en 50 preguntas.

  - Si el **Usuario A** crea una etiqueta que cae en desuso y **Usuario B** la usa de nuevo en el futuro, el **Usuario A** continúa siendo el que se lleva el crédito de haber creado la etiqueta, a efectos de esta medalla ([fuente](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/16017))

---

#### Vox Pópuli

- bronce; entregada una vez
- Realizar 40 votos - el máximo (límite) diario.

  - Cada "día" va de la medianoche UTC al momento antes de la medianoche, UTC; los días no se cuentan en tiempo local
  - Puede que el sistema te restrinja a menos de 40 votos diarios.
  - Recibes dos tipos de votos diarios: diez solo pueden usarse en preguntas ("Q-votes") y 30 pueden usarse en preguntas o respuestas ("QA-votes").
  - Cuando votas en una pregunta, el sistema intenta usar tus Q-votes antes de tus QA-votes.
  - Cuando solamente te quedan cinco QA-votes en un día dado, tras cada voto empieza a aparecer el contador "Te quedan **n** votos hoy".
  - Cuando el contador empieza nunca vuelve atrás ese día. Por tanto, si al principio del día votas mayormente a respuestas, el contador empezará a aparecer cuando te queden más de cinco votos en total (es decir, incluyendo Q y QA), haciendo que sea imposible llegar a 40 votos ese día.
- [Sugerido inicialmente](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/89534) por waffles. Una [propuesta refinada](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/89547) por Bill the Lizard se [implementó](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/90256) años después.
- Véase la entrada de blog [Vote For This Question or The Kitten Gets It](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/05/vote-for-this-question-or-the-kitten-gets-it/)

Answer (score 2):

## Medallas por etiquetas

[Vuelve a la pregunta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2699/83)

---

### ¿Qué son las medallas por etiquetas?

Los usuarios pueden recibir medallas por sus contribuciones positivas en etiquetas. Cada medalla por etiqueta tiene el mismo nombre que la etiqueta por la que se entrega.

Cuando un usuario cumple los requisitos para una medalla de etiqueta que nunca se ha entregado, el sistema la crea y la entrega. Estas medallas se muestran con un fondo blanco, a diferencia de las otras medallas que lo tienen negro.

Información extraída de la [respuesta de waffles♦](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63835/what-are-tag-badges-how-do-they-work/63836#63836):

- A diferencia de las medallas "normales", las medallas por etiquetas se quitan si ya no se cumplen los requisitos por los que se entregaron.
- Una etiqueta debe aparecer como mínimo en 100 preguntas para que se pueda entregar una medalla por esa etiqueta.

---

### ¿Qué es la reputación por etiqueta?

La reputación por etiqueta es el resultado de combinar todos los votos positivos (+1) con los negativos (-1) que se han acumulado en las **respuestas** de una etiqueta determinada (los votos en preguntas no cuentan). Del mismo modo, las respuestas que son wiki de comunidad o que están eliminadas no cuentan para esta reputación.

La reputación por etiqueta se recalcula cada día, a las 03:00 UTC.

---

#### Bronce

- Reputación total de 100
- solamente cuentan **respuestas** que no sean wiki de comunidad ni estén eliminadas
- se debe tener un mínimo de 20 respuestas en esa etiqueta

---

#### Plata

- Reputación total de 400
- respuestas no wiki y no eliminadas
- mínimo de 80 respuestas

---

#### Oro

- Reputación total de 1000
- respuestas no wiki y no eliminadas
- mínimo de 200 respuestas
- desbloquea el [poderoso martillo de Mjölnir](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/230865/increase-close-vote-weight-for-gold-tag-badge-holders)