# ¿Las recompensas aumentan la puntuación de las etiquetas?

Tags: soporte, etiquetas, recompensas

¿Las [recompensas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/bounty) que se dan, influyen también en las puntuaciones de las [etiquetas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tags)?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Para tenerlo claro: te refieres a la reputación por etiqueta de un usuario, ¿verdad?

Comment: Si @fedorqui... estaba leyendo los comentarios bajo tu respuesta y tendría que dar por parte la razón a Pikoh. Dices:  _"...al no mencionar este no forma parte de X..."_  Vale y seguro que la respuesta sea no (sea razonable y/o por lógica)... peeeero en realidad... no esta en ningún lado documentado (literalmente)...  :)

Comment: ¡Genial! Nunca está de más preguntar para salir de dudas y ahora sí tendremos documentación no oficial, pero pseudo oficiosa :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No.

Las puntuaciones de las etiquetas se obtienen única y exclusivamente a partir de los votos que se recibe en las **respuestas no wiki de comunidad**.

Por tanto:

- tu puntuación de etiquetas (o reputación de etiqueta, como suele decirse) subirá en 1 cada vez que recibas un voto positivo en una respuesta de ese tipo,
- y bajará en 1 cada vez que recibas un voto negativo en una respuesta con esas mismas condiciones.

Véase por ejemplo en [tu perfil](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/6491/aldanux?tab=tags) cuando pones el cursor sobre una de ellas:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

De [Lista de todas las medallas con su descripción completa](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2699/83):

> ### ¿Qué es la reputación por etiqueta?
>
> La reputación por etiqueta es el resultado de combinar todos los votos positivos (+1) con los negativos (-1) que se han acumulado en las **respuestas** de una etiqueta determinada (los votos en preguntas no cuentan). Del mismo modo, las respuestas que son wiki de comunidad o que están eliminadas no cuentan para esta reputación.

Comment: Perdona fedorqui, pero ahi se habla de wiki. En ningún momento se mencionan las recompensas

Comment: @Pikoh añadí también una referencia a _qué es la reputación por etiqueta_.

Comment: Vale,creo que tienes toda la razón, para las etiquetas computan solo los votos positivos y negativos en tu respuesta, no los puntos de reputación. Eso es lo que puede llevar a confusión :)

Comment: @Pikoh sí, lo mismo no me expliqué demasiado bien. He editado para intentar mejorar el redactado. Corrige lo que creas que no está claro.

Comment: Para mi ahora esta clarisimo. No hay necesidad de tocar nada ;)