# Problema de interpretacion

Tags: soporte, bug, estado-en-revisión, medallas

La descripcion de la medalla de plata Convencion dice lo siguiente:

> 10 publicaciones con una puntuación de 2 en meta

Link: https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges?tab=General&filter=unearned.

Esto me deja la siguiente duda:

Si yo hago 10 publicaciones en meta y 5 publicaciones obtienen 2ptos, 3 publicaciones obtienen 4ptos, y 2 publicaciones obtienen 3ptos, tal como esta escrito la definicion de esa medalla no pudiera obtenerla, ya que la totalidad de esas 10 publicaciones tendrian que tener 2ptos.

De realmente funcionar como esta escrito ahora, en mi apreciacion personal lo veo absurdo, ya que debiera decir:

> 10 publicaciones con una puntuación de **al menos 2 ptos** en meta

Comment: Es dos o más. Lo mismo ocurre con la descripción de otras medallas.

Comment: @fedorqui'SOdejadedañar', y se puede arreglar?

Comment: Tal vez sí, pero en Meta.SE se ha descrito repetidamente ([ejemplo](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/119343/209901)) y no se ha modificado. La descripción suele ser muy corta, de ahí que se cree la pregunta [Lista de todas las medallas con su descripción completa](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2699/83) para ampliar y resolver equívocos.

Comment: opino que ese enlace con la descripcionde completa de las medalla esta muy rebuscado... en mi vida lo habia visto... y dudo que alguien lo vaya a encontrar si no viene al. meta y hace la busaqueda... deberia ser conbina con las lista de medalla que ya uno se ha ganado... y tener un acceso visible en el perfil... saludos